# How to record a video or take a picture while streaming on Raspberry pi

Tags: raspberry-pi

I want to build a video streamer which can record video and take picture when user want to do that. I saw this video works: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VTZMOHE8v-Q

But when I setup the streamer use the guideline of http://videos.cctvcamerapros.com/raspberry-pi/how-to-setup-video-streaming-server.html
I can't record a video or picture in the terminal, I got this error:

```
pi@raspberrypi /var/www $ raspivid -o vid.h264

mmal: mmal_vc_component_enable: failed to enable component: ENOSPC

mmal: camera component couldn't be enabled

mmal: main: Failed to create camera component

mmal: Failed to run camera app. Please check for firmware updates
```

This error appears when call the camera to record a video or take a picture while it is doing another task. I got the reply from linkto blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/video-streaming-with-flask/page/0#comments

But is there any way to record a video while streaming? It seems every modern camera has this function. Thanks!

Comment: Here is a nice example (including code): http://www.instructables.com/id/Raspberry-Pi-as-low-cost-HD-surveillance-camera/

Comment: Thanks! This tutorial didn't mention whether it can stream and record the video at same time, but I found one simple solution last night: http://elinux.org/RPi-Cam-Web-Interface. But how they make it works?